# Unable to install composer-rest-server v0.19.5 in ubuntu 16.05

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

My composer version is 19.5 but I have installed pug also.[Error image of bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnW4W.jpg)

Comment: it would be better if ppl. could help on real issue , rather than correcting english

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed node version 8 
    node --version    //  v8.x

then hit-
    npm install -g composer-rest-server@0.19.0

Comment: But I need composer-rest-server version equal to or higher than  0.19.5. and i have node version v8.x using nvm, for that